# String searching in Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am wanting to create a Where statement within my Linq statement, but have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

I would like to split a string value, and then search using each array item in the Where clause.

In my normal Sql statement I would simply loop through the string array, and build up there Where clause then either pass this to a stored procedure, or just execute the sql string. But am not sure how to do this with Linq to Entity?

```
( From o In db.TableName Where o.Field LIKE Stringvalue Select o ).ToList()
```

Comment: Can you show how you'd do this in SQL, just to clarify your position as re-reading your question I'm no longer sure my answer satisfies your query.

Comment: Are you trying to look for values that match every single item in the array (AND), or any one (OR)?

Comment: For my SQL if I were just to write out a string and execute it I would write...

dim Sql as string = " select fields from table where "
For each s as string in Stringvalue.split(",")
Sql += " fieldname like '%" & s & "%' or "
end for
remove the final 'or' from the string and run this sql

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(from o in db.Tablename
    where o.Field.Contains(Stringvalue)
    select o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do dynamic construction it's probably best to use an expression tree. Give this a shot:

```
IQueryable<EntityType> query = db.Tablename;
Expression<Func<EntityType, bool>> expression = null;

foreach (string item in yourString.Split(","))
{
    string localItem = item; // so that we don't close over the loop variable

    Expression<Func<EntityType, bool>> exp = x => x.FieldName.Contains(localItem);

    if (expression == null)
    {
        expression = exp;
    }
    else
    {
        expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(expression.Body,  
            Expression.Invoke(exp,expression.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())), 
            expression.Parameters);
    }
}

var results = query.Where(expression).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Adam
This works, although only returns a list which match the final item in the string array.
So if the string value was "a,b,c,d" it would only return those matching "d".
Is there a way to join the query within the for loop so that the final query.ToList() contains query.where(x => x.fieldname.contains("a")) and query.where(x => x.fieldname.contains("b")) .... ?

Comment: You could use Union to chain the queries together, like my answer

Comment: @Jim: Give this edit a shot. My original answer was wrong in that it a) was designed to be an `AND`, when you really want an `OR`, and b) it closed over the loop variable (d'oh!), which is why it only matched the last condition.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the delay.
The code produces an error of: "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Answer (score 0):

```
var fcs = from c in Contacts
          where c.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(e.value.ToLower())
          select c;
```

You can use any string functions like contains, startswith etc

Comment: Many people use the ToLower() trick, but you don't have to. StartsWith has an overload in which you can supply StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Misinterpreted your question, how about:

```
string filters = "a,b,c,d";
var result = from filter in filters.Split(',')
             from record In db.TableName
             where record.Field.Contains(filter)
```

Comment: This is an equality comparison, not a `LIKE` operation.

Comment: This works when the text I am searching with is exact, but not for partial matches. But thanks for the code as it will come in handy down the line

Answer (score 0):

Air code building on Adam's answer and using [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) to chain the results together, emulating AND rather than OR.

**EDIT** I removed my recommendation to use Distinct because Union filters out duplicates.

```
var query = null; 

foreach(string item in yourString.Split(",")) 
{ 
    var newquery = db.Tablename.Where(x => x.FieldName.Contains(item));  
    if (query == null) {  
      query = query.union(newquery);    
    } else {  
      query = newquery;  
    }  
}  

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: hmm no this does not seem to work for me. I get the error:
InnerException = {"The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."}

Comment: I think that means the types don't implement IComparable? Does that sound right?

Comment: Actually I was wrong: you don't need to use Distinct, Union already filters out duplicates